# group by JSON Column that contains an array

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2016

I have the following table:

[image: Table]

that contains these data:

[image: Data]

How can I group by my array items in my JSON Column? and get this result:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with `CROSS APPLY` to make it.

```
SELECT
    col1,
     UserID
FROM T t1
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(t1.Roles)
    WITH
        (
            col1 varchar(50) N'$'
        ) AS a
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1be0f42467a95b72c0821efeb698d79e)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use OPENJSON, here is an alternative

```
Select
    aRole, COUNT(*) as cnt
From (

    Select
        a.ID
        ,b.Items as aRole
    From 
        (Select *
            ,replace(replace(replace(Roles,'[',''),']',''),'"','') as Rolesx
         From JSONgroup) a
    Cross Apply dbo.Split(a.Rolesx, ',') b
) c
 group by aRole
```